# How to string replace in a list of phone numbers in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, replace

I have these phone numbers in a list:

```
+61 2 3456 2718
03 2756 2876
4567 8937 
+61 5 6573 8593
05 8583 7932
```

I want to remove the first digit, if 0, and put +61 in every number. How can I do this?

```
import re 
for i in phone:
    print(re.sub(r"(\+?\d{3})(\d{4})(\d+)", r"\1 \2 \3", i))
    re.sub('^\d+', '', i)
```

Comment: phone number:  [+61 2 3456 2718], [03 2756 2876],[4567 8937], [+61 5 6573 8593],[05 8583 7932]

Comment: yes that is my question. thanks emma

Answer (score 1):

If all the phone numbers start with either a `0` or some international code like `+61` (or another international code) and you don't need any other checks, your code could be as simple (and legible) as:

```
fixed_phone_numbers = [f'+61{n[1:]}' if n[0] == '0' else n for n in phone_numbers]
```

If, for some reason, you'd want to do this in Python 2:

```
fixed_phone_numbers = ['+61' + n[1:] if n[0] == '0' else n for n in phone_numbers]
```

Comment: thanks Grismar, Here I want to use regex instead of simple loops

Comment: @KingStone because Grismar using [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) which is a new feature coming from Python 3.6 onward. But you can use [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) in Python 2.X versions instead of [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) or can accept the edited answer.

Comment: @subaskhanal I think a list comprehension is a more Pythonic solution, there is really little to no advantage to using regex in this case, unless you have more restrictions for the match - hence the assumption.

Comment: yes I appreciate your thought but there is regex compulsion in my code. Anyway thanks for your logic. I got something to learn for you as well.

Comment: 'regex compulsion' seems to be a common affliction on SO... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
phone = ["+61 2 3456 2718",
"03 2756 2876",
"4567 8937 ",
"+61 5 6573 8593",
"05 8583 7932"]
import re 
for i in phone:
    if(not i.startswith('+61')):
      if(re.match(r'^0', i)):
        i = re.sub('^0', '+61', i)
      else:
        i = '+61 ' + i
    print(i)

+61 2 3456 2718
+613 2756 2876
+61 4567 8937
+61 5 6573 8593
+615 8583 7932
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked a lot but I need every phone number starting with +61. which isn't working here.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check the first character .If it is '0' then replaced the string by "+61"+ "substring_of_phone_number_from_position_1" (i[1:]).

```
import re 
for i in phone:
    if i[0]=='0':
        i='+61'+i[1:]
    elif i[0]!='+':
        i='+61'+i
```

Comment: Hi Mahbubcseju, this code works when there is 0 at the first but I need every phone number to start with +61 mean the phone number which do not have country code but not started with 0 also need to be updated.

Comment: let  8068676 a number so it will be +618068676? Edited!

Comment: thanks that's what i want but I want to solve this problem using regex. and I am having problem on its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps :-). I used just regex for this

```
In [1]: strings = """+61 2 3456 2718
   ...: 03 2756 2876
   ...: 4567 8937 
   ...: +61 5 6573 8593
   ...: 05 8583 7932"""
In [3]: import re

In [12]: for phoneno in strings.split('\n'):
    ...:     print(re.sub(r'^(0|\+61|)',r'+61',phoneno))
    ...:     
    ...:     

+61 2 3456 2718
+613 2756 2876
+614567 8937 
+61 5 6573 8593
+615 8583 7932
```